# Python Taskkill hangs on windows when no tasks are present

Tags: python, windows

Im trying to kill all chrome tasks in my code

The problem is that after running it, if no chrome windows are already open, the console just hangs waiting for me to input enter.

I tried different suggestions to fix this, but it still just hangs,

here is what I tried

```
def kill_process(process_name):
```

## Iterate over all running processes

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
    if proc.info['name'] == f"{process_name}.exe":
        # Kill the process
        proc.kill()
        print(f"Process '{process_name}' killed successfully.")
        return

# If the process was not found
print(f"Process '{process_name}' not found.")
```

and this

```
def kill_process(process_name):
# Construct the command to kill the process
command = f"taskkill /f /im {process_name}.exe"

# Attempt to kill the process
try:
    # Open a subprocess with the command
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    
    # Wait for the process to terminate
    process.wait(timeout=5)  # Adjust the timeout as needed
    
    # Get the return code
    return_code = process.returncode
    
    # Check if the process was terminated successfully
    if return_code == 0:
        print(f"Process '{process_name}' terminated successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to terminate process '{process_name}'.")
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    # Process took too long to terminate
    print(f"Timed out while terminating process '{process_name}'.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

and simply just this

```
    try:
    subprocess.run("taskkill /f /im chrome.exe", check=True, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)
except:
    print('no chrome processes open')
```

it always hangs